# Check all checkbox in ExpandableListView (Android)

Tags: java, android

I am using `ExpandableListView`. In both group and child, there are checkboxes. How to do the following requirement?

When user check the checkbox of group, check all the box of its child.

I think I need to overwrite the `BaseExpandableListAdapter`,
but I don't know what should be filled in. Thank You.

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, 
  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
          boolean isChecked) 
        {
            //Fill in what?
        }

    });

}
```

There is a similar question, but I don't understand its solution:
[How to get all childs view in group with ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924977/how-to-get-all-childs-view-in-group-with-expandablelistview)

Answer (score 2):

The linked answer I believe is saying you should keep track of the state of your checked groups in an array list.  Then, in your `getChildView` method for your `BaseExpandableListAdapter` you would do a check to see if the group for the child is present.

Here is my implementation, I'm using a hashmap instead of an arraylist:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CheckBox check__bookmark = (CheckBox) child_row.findViewById(R.id._checkBox);

    if (mapp.group_bookmark_s_checked.containsKey((groupPosition)) == true)                 
        check__bookmark.setChecked(true);
    else
        check__bookmark.setChecked(false);
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    CheckBox PlayGroupSelected = 
                 (CheckBox) group_row.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_group_checkBox);        

    if (mapp.group_bookmark_s_checked.containsKey((groupPosition)) == true)                 
        PlayGroupSelected.setChecked(true);
    else
        PlayGroupSelected.setChecked(false);

    PlayGroupSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new BookmarkGroupCheckedChangeListener(groupPosition, mapp, group_row));
}
```

Now in your listener you manage the state by removing and adding to your state object.  I used `notifyDataSetChanged()` because the children weren't refreshing once drawn on the check state change.  Not sure if that was the right way to solve that problem but it did the trick.

```
class BookmarkGroupCheckedChangeListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener  {

    private int mPosition;
    MyApplication mapp;
    RelativeLayout mgroup_row;


    BookmarkGroupCheckedChangeListener(int position, MyApplication app, RelativeLayout group_row) {
        mapp = app;
        mPosition = position;
        mgroup_row = group_row;
    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked == true) {
            mapp.group_bookmark_s_checked.put((mPosition), new Boolean(true));
            Log.v("DEBUG:", "Group Bookmark Checked On at " + mPosition);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if (mapp.group_bookmark_s_checked.containsKey(mPosition)) {
            mapp.group_bookmark_s_checked.remove((mPosition));
            Log.v("DEBUG:", "Checked Off at " + mPosition);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. notifyDataSetChanged(); is important. tanks