# Android- Expendable Listview Checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have checkbox in both, group and child in Expendable listview. Now, i want to do , when i click on group checkbox, all child checkbox of that group, will select automatically and instantly. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, so perhaps an answer is no longer needed, but I believe this same question was answered here: [How to get all childs view in group with ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924977/how-to-get-all-childs-view-in-group-with-expandablelistview)

Comment: If they're identical, you can flag question duplicated.

Comment: @Yul, Good suggestion, thanks.  I did think about doing that and may yet do it.  The questions do seem to be the same, though I wanted to see if the poster of this question found the answer to the other helpful, since I think there is some detail lacking there that may make it difficult to understand to someone relatively inexperienced with listviews (I count myself in that category).  Also, the title of the other question does not really reflect what that poster or this one was trying to do.